# How do I make my system wait 5 seconds before continuing?

Tags: java, timestamp, project

I'm currently working on a Black Jack game in a school project. When the machine rolls, I want to make it wait 5 seconds each time it rolls to make it more exciting. How do I do this?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean bny waiting ? Stop the main thread of execution from going ahead for 5 seconds or just freeze the User Interface?

Comment: Are you just looking for `Thread.sleep(5000);`? Also, why is this tagged with `javascript`?

Comment: Does Javascript has anything to do with it?

Comment: people must be having a good day, any other time a post like this would be -6 by now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Thread#sleep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-):

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

The method can throw `InterruptedException` if any thread has interrupted the current thread. Usually you would catch the exception and handle it but if your program is single threaded, you don't need to worry about it. So you can just *specify* that the method calling `Thread.sleep` throws an `InterruptedException`:

```
public void foo() throws InterruptedException {
    ...
    Thread.sleep();
    ...
}
```

Comment: error: unreported exception InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

So how do I implement the thread in my loop?

if(machineSum < 18){
            machineSum = machineSum + roll;
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("Machine got: " + machineSum);
         }

Comment: @user3703289 you could use try catch 

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if(machineSum < 18){ 
            machineSum = machineSum + roll;
            try {
              Thread.sleep(5000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Machine got: " + machineSum);
        }

Comment: I got it! Had to implement: throws InterruptedException in my main. THanks a lot for ur help and patience!

Answer (score 0):

You can use threading to sleep 5 seconds your current thread

```
try {
Thread.sleep(5000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

I Think this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using the **Thread** Class with method  **sleep**

[Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) Says : 
sleep(long millis);

Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers.

Example:-

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you should you use a very large loop repetition in any programming language to create a delay.